# Want to pass the cookies to the webview to load a webpage

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, webview, jsoup

I had Successful login to a website using jsoup and I obtained cookies from Jsoup cookies function in Map but I am struck at something.After successful login I Want to open a webpage of the website in the webview but the webpage redirects to the login page because cookies are not successfully passed to the webview and I don't know why. The page wants cookies of successful login to load that page

Here is the login page url.

http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/

and page I want to load after Successful Login

http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/PersonalInfo.aspx

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ebad.bu;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    String url = "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/";
    Map<String, String> logingcookies;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog,progressDialoge;

    Button login, personal;
    TextView Enrollement, password, E;
    String enrol = "";
    String pass = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        personal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pers);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Enrollement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Enrollment);
                enrol = Enrollement.getText().toString();

                password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
                pass = password.getText().toString();

                new Title().execute();


            }
        });



    }

    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;
        String father;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Title");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(1000).execute();
                Document doc = loginForm.parse();
                String viewstate = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").attr("value");
                String stategenerator = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]").attr("value");
                String Eventvalidation = doc.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").attr("value");


                doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                        .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                        .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                        .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate)
                        .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", stategenerator)
                        .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", Eventvalidation)
                        .data("ctl00$Body$ENROLLMENTTextBox$tb", enrol)
                        .data("ctl00$Body$ENROLLMENTTextBox$cv_vce_ClientState", "")
                        .data("ctl00$Body$PasswordTextBox$tb", pass)
                        .data("ctl00$Body$PasswordTextBox$cv_vce_ClientState", "")
                        .data("ctl00$Body$LoginButton", "Login")
                        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                        .post();

                logingcookies = loginForm.cookies();


                title = doc.select("div[id=ctl00_Accounts]").html();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {




            /*Intent showadditionmenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Per.class);
            //showadditionmenu.putStringArrayListExtra("logingcookies", (ArrayList<String>) logingcookies);
            showadditionmenu.putExtra("logingcookies", String.valueOf(logingcookies));
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(showadditionmenu);*/

          /*  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Per.class);
            i.putExtra("hashMap",hashMap );
            startActivity(i);
*/
            hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>(logingcookies);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,wee.class);
            i.putExtra("hashMap",hashMap );
            startActivity(i);

          /*  E = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
            E.setText(title);
            progressDialog.dismiss();*/
        }


    }

}
```

I have passed the saved cookie to the activity that load the webpage in webivew.. Here is the other activity;

Wee.java

```
package com.example.ebad.bu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Ebad on 11/8/2015.
 */
public class wee extends Activity {

    String url= "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/PersonalInfo.aspx";
    HashMap<String ,String> hashMap;
    Map<String,String> map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        hashMap = (HashMap<String,String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewe);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url,hashMap);

    }

}
```

Is there any way that I can view that webpage without logging in again to the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but using [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) ahould work.

Usage should be something like this:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie(); //optional
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Then loop over your cookies using the [setCookie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

**Note:** If useing lollipop and up you should also use [setAcceptThirdPartyCookies](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean)).

Good luck.

Comment: CookieSyncManager is now deprecated

Comment: You should read the documentation:
"This class was deprecated in API level 21.
The WebView now automatically syncs cookies as necessary. You no longer need to create or use the CookieSyncManager. To manually force a sync you can use the CookieManager method flush() which is a synchronous replacement for sync()."

First there are not a lot of apps around right now with minimum SDK 21.
Second this is Only relevant if you use the WebView to obtain your cookies, which you don't. so if you want to set cookies to your web view i can't imagine a better way.